# Does cppUnit use fork() when it launch each unit test?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, cppunit

I'm using cppunit for the unit tests of my project.

And I m wondering if the cppunit launch each unit test in a new fork() system call because:

- Using fork will allow to create a new address space in which to run each unit test
- Using fork will allow to keep the unit tests running even if one of them causes a crash.

I defined a global variable and then I tried to change the global variable in the unit test and change that has no affect in the parent process but unfortunally I found that global variable is changed.

So by default cppunit does not support launching unit test with `fork()`. And I m wondering if there is macros in cppunit that could initiate unit test with `fork()` ?

My tests are defined in the following way:

```
class MYTest : public CppUnit::TestCase {

   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE( MYTest );
   CPPUNIT_TEST( getRetryValueTest );
   CPPUNIT_TEST( getRetryValueTest2 );
   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END(); 

   public:
      virtual void setUp();

      void getRetryValueTest();
      void getRetryValueTest2();
};
```

Comment: Typically this is only done for "death tests" where the expectation is the test will cause the application to terminate if an error occurs (think cascading exceptions). Can't give a definitive answer here since I'm not familiar with cppUnit.

Comment: Seems like it would be easy enough to check for yourself. Write two tests, and have each print the current process ID. Do they both print the same values?

Comment: That would be a good way to ensure that one test doesn't influence another, but sometimes you WANT tests to affect each other [without having to save state in a file, or some such]. I would have thought it ideal to have that as an option - although I don't know how cppunit works.

Comment: @RobKennedy, you are right it's a claver idea, but the cppunit could support both and could have macros to initiate unit tests with fork. and if they exists I wich to know them

Comment: If tests influence each other then they are not correct unit tests...

Comment: @R.. exactelly that what I want to check before using cppunit in all my test cases. otherwise I have to use other one

Comment: @MOHAMED: Considering `CppUnit` is cross platform, and `fork()` is not, I highly doubt that it forks for each test.

Comment: @Mats: If you have a situation like that you would use fixtures, not different tests that happen to be related.

Comment: Ehm, but just because something is portable to different platforms doesn't mean that it doesn't use the "easiest way" to achieve something on each platform, and to me `fork()` is a very quick way to achieve "make a copy of this process to run the test within". Other platforms may need different code to achieve that, but it's not to say that this isn't the way its done on a platform that actually has `fork()`?

Comment: using fork will allow to create a new address space in which to run each unit test.

Comment: Using fork will allow to keep the unit tests running even if one of them causes a crash.

Comment: @MOHAMED: If the goal of separating the tests is to ensure that the remaining tests will be reliable even after one test has invoked undefined behavior due to a bug, then yes, `fork` makes sense. But if you *expect* one test to have side-effects that are visible to the next test, then you're doing unit testing wrong (and the code you're testing is designed wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Cppunit does not use fork to separate tests. However tests in the same suite are separate objects so each test has its own set of variables and are therefore independent from each other and can't influence each other.